# closing app after sending group sms

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to send to group sms with cordova-sms-plugin.
My issue that all sms sent but the app is closing right after.
What I want to show message like last task should do. But the app close without showing any message.
I am using ionic 1.x,

My code is:

```
  .factory("SendSmsAll", function ($cordovaSms, $q) {
    return {
      sendSms: function (contacts, text) {
        //CONFIGURATION
        var options = {
          replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
          android: {
            // intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
            intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
          }
        };
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var promises = [];

        function lastTask() {

          var donePopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'done sending sms',
            template: 'all sms sent'
          });
          donePopup();
          defer.resolve();
        }

        angular.forEach(contacts.filter(withNumberOnly), function (contact) {
          promises.push($cordovaSms.send(contact.number, text, options, $q.defer().resolve(), $q.defer().reject()));
        });
        function withNumberOnly(contact) {
          return contact.hasOwnProperty('number');
        }

        $q.all(promises).then(lastTask);
        return defer.promise;
      }
```

Comment: what do you mean by *all sms sent but the app is closing right after?* please elaborate more on this, what is expected behavior though?

Comment: after it sent all sms the app closing and not doing last task as it should do